# Create an ArrayList then Search the List and allow the user to change part of the list or not

Tags: java, arraylist

Our assignment is to create an to-do list using Arraylist coding.

Then change the code so that it ask the user to input a string after the list has been inputted, it will tell the user that if that String exists in the list.

Finally, If the string has been found allow the user to input another String and it replaces the original String.  then print out the list.

here is what i have:  I am unsure how to continue.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayListDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  ArrayList<String> toDoList = new ArrayList<String>();
  System.out.println("Enter items for the list, when prompted.");
  boolean done = false;
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

  while (!done)
  {
      System.out.println("Type an entry:");
      String entry = keyboard.nextLine( );
      toDoList.add(entry);
      System.out.print("More items for the list? ");

      String ans = keyboard.nextLine( );
      if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
          done = true;
  }

  System.out.println("The list contains:");
  int listSize = toDoList.size( );
  for (int position = 0; position < listSize; position++)
      System.out.println(toDoList.get(position));
    )
 )
```

I notice that I could incorporate:

```
ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>();
String search = "a";
int searchListLength = searchList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
if (searchList.get(i).contains(search)) {
//Where do I put it after the List is printed or before?  Any Help would be appricated
}
}
```

Here is a sample output of what I am trying to do:

```
 Enter items for the list, when prompted.

 Type an entry:

 Alice

 More items for the list? yes

 Type an entry:

 Bob

 More items for the list? yes

 Type an entry:

 Carol

 More items for the list? no

 The list contains:

 Alice

 Bob

 Carol

 Enter a String to search for:

 Bob

 Enter a String to replace with:

 Bill

 Bob found!

 The list contains:

 Alice

 Bill

 Carol
```

If the user searches for an item not found then it tells them "item" not Found!

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I need to change the Program so that after the user inputs their list,  it will then prompt them to search the list.  if that search is in the list it will prompt them to change that particular item they dont have to though

Comment: Just added a sample output.  I am unsure how to wrtie a code to allow a user to search their list after inputting the list and if need be change that particular item they searched for if found!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll use [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29) to find the index, and then if item exists(`index != -1`) you'll get an index which you can then use to replace the item using [`set(int index, E item)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#set%28int,%20E%29).

As an example, you can do something like..

```
boolean search=true;
while(search) {
  System.out.print("Search..");
  String searchFor = keyboard.nextLine();
  int ind = searchList.indexOf(searchFor);
  if (ind == -1) {
    System.out.println("Not Found");
  } else {
    System.out.print("Replace with.. ");
    String replaceWith = keyboard.nextLine();
    searchList.set(ind, replaceWith);
  }
  System.out.print("Continue searching.. ");
  String ans = keyboard.nextLine( );
  if (!ans.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
    search = false;
}
```

Comment: I see so if i use your advice where do I place it?

Comment: I see so I take your advice and add it to the entire code or do I replace it with the top half?

Comment: thank you that works after minor changes.  Also once that is done I need to reprint the new list dont I just use the same system.println codeing? nvm got it